# Color of emacs margins

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

With the following in my .emacs I get narrow margins in text-mode buffers:

```
(defun my-set-margins ()
  "Set margins in current buffer."
  (setq left-margin-width 30)
  (setq right-margin-width 30))

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-set-margins)
```

How can I change the color of the lines that appear to delimit these margins so that it's the same as my background color and not black like they are now?

[image: Current margins with black lines]

**EDIT**

I know more now and this is my question:

How do I add a hook to turn of the fringes in text-mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "#2E2920" :foreground "#2E2920")
```

`#2E2920` being my background color.